# How to use jquery get content with tags in xml

Tags: xml, jquery

first I have an xml :

```
<app id="id-1">
    <html_code>
           <div id="id-1" class="portlet">
                  <div class="portlet-header">Links</div>
                  <div class="portlet-content">id-1</div>
           </div>
    </html_code>
</app>
```

I want use jquery $.ajax to get the content in  tags
I use

```
 $.ajax({
   ……
   success: function (xml) {
          alert($(xml).find("app[id='id-1']").find("html_code").text());
   }

});
```

however, it only alert "links","id-1",but I want the `<html_code>`'s all content include `<div>` tags,

so how can I achieve that use jquery ?or I should back to javascript use "getxml"……

thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the raw unfiltered goodness, like this:

```
alert($(xml).find("app[id='id-1']").find("html_code").html());
```

Comment: yes,thank you ,I konw what's wrong with me ,in the $.ajax the datatype I write is "xml",so the case above ,I have ever use "html()" ,it can not be achieved,you remaind me ,so I correct it to ""html",finally it successed!