# Jquery Parsing Raw dump XMl node containing html - YQL

Tags: jquery, xml, yql

I am using YQL and the results are being returned in XML, I have not opted for Json, this Time since I need to emit the exact html under the Results tag of YQL.
So i give a call to $.Ajax and get the xml and find the "results" node in the xml.

when i do an alert or appending to a div or a body of html, somehow it seems the whole of Div's and Table's and Td's and Tr's are getting ripped before rendering.
I did an alert still didn't see the full raw html.

```
 $("#result").html("<i>Loading...</i>");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: yql,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    info = $(xml).find('results');
                    alert(info.text());
                    $("body").html(info.text());
                }
```

What am i missing over here.
CDATA for covering html inside xml is not an option over here, just trying to render what is being served from YQL.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone encountered this issue.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this problem, and dug up a couple of solutions.  The first and easiest would be to do this:

```
$("#result").html("<i>Loading...</i>");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: yql,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (xml) {
                info = $(xml).find('results').html();
                alert(info);
                $("body").html(info);
            }
```

You can find that here (check in the response to the answer): [How to use jquery get content with tags in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334796/how-to-use-jquery-get-content-with-tags-in-xml)

The second solution that worked for me was best explained here: [Getting HTML from XML with JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980786/getting-html-from-xml-with-javascript-jquery)

Comment: I got my stuff working by doing this way.
<code>
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#result').html("Loading...");
            var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql/...?format=xml&callback=?';
            $.getJSON(yql,
        function (data) {
            if (data.results[0]) {
                var data = data.results[0];
                $('#result').html(data);
            } else {
                var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
                $('#result').html(errormsg);
            }
        });
</code>